# .net Chart link image

Tags: asp.net, css, charts

never worked with .net before so please excuse me if this sounds stupid.

On the page im working on I have the following...

```
<Series>
<asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Pie" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Disabled">
</asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
<asp:ChartArea Name="SearchEngineArea">
<Area3DStyle Enable3D="True" />
</asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>

<div class="bottomBox"><a href="/" class="seochart">View large</a></div>
```

The Div class "seochart" calls a lightbox, The idea is that view large calls the image outputted from the .net Chart.

How would I go about putting my  chart as the href?

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't know what a "lightbox" is, but I think in your case you could resolve this by writing a webservice or http handler which would return a png or jpg image. Therefore, your href for your anchor element would be the URL for that webservice (something like: http://yoursite.com/yourService.asmx?etc=something).
In the webmethod on your webservice (server-side), you write C# code using the winform version of Chart class (from System.windows.Forms.DataVisualisation namespace). Once you instantiate a chart, you have access to the SaveImage method, and from there you can stream this image back to the client-side.
Hope this helps.